# How to tally wins and losses using SUM and CASE?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008

I am trying to tally the wins and losses for any given bike.  Each time a user votes, he casts a vote for one bike (1) and a vote against another bike (0).

My vote table looks like this:

```
VoteID --- BikeID ---- Vote
1          100         1
2          101         0
3          100         0
4          101         1
5          102         1
6          100         0
7          102         0
8          101         1
```

I want my results to look like this when I run a query for a specific bike

```
Wins -- Losses
5       6
```

Right now, my results look like this:

```
Wins --- Losses
5        NULL
NULL     6
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN Vote = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Wins,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Vote = 0 THEN 1 END) AS Losses
FROM     Votes
WHERE    BikeID = 101
GROUP BY Vote
```

What do I need to do to get the results on one line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN Vote = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Wins,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Vote = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Losses
FROM     Votes
WHERE    BikeID = 101
```

The problem is your case statements did not cover all conditions, and so were returning null for the cases where they did not account for.

Also, you did not need the group by vote, since you aren't actually selecting the vote outside the aggregates.

Comment: Wow, I just got rid of the "group by" and got my answer.  Thanks! There is only 1 and 0 for the possible answers. I don't think the ELSE is necessary, is it?

Comment: I would keep it in there for completeness.  Clearly it's not necessary, as you have it working without it.  I think it reads more clearly with it in there.

Comment: The `ELSE 0` is needed in case there are no negative (or positive) rows. Leaving it out implies `ELSE NULL` and the `SUM()` would be `NULL`, not `0`.

Comment: @ypercube: Actually no, a single NULL would not affect the entire result. SUM() would only return NULL if there were no values to add up, which can be either when there are no rows at all or when all the values are NULL. This is true for SQL Server 2005 and later, and so it's true for the OP's case. But you may be right with regard to earlier versions, I just can't tell for sure.

Comment: @Andriy: That's what I meant, too. If there are only positive votes, then `Losses` would be calculated as `SUM(NULL,NULL,NULL)` -> `NULL`.

Comment: @ypercube: Ah, I see now what you meant, sorry for being dumb.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Vote` is `bit`:

```
SELECT
  Wins   = SUM(0 + Vote),
  Losses = SUM(1 - Vote)
FROM Votes
WHERE BikeID = 101
```

If `Vote` is not `bit`, you can get rid of `0 +` in the `Wins` calculation.

Comment: Vote is an int, using only 0 and 1 as options. Your SQL looks really readable and clean.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Vote` is `Int` and takes only `0` or `1` values, you could also use this:

```
SELECT
  SUM(Vote) AS Wins, 
  COUNT(*) - SUM(Vote) AS Losses
FROM Votes
WHERE BikeID = 101
```